# do-while loop does not go through while condition C#

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, do-while

I wrote a do-while loop but it does not run through while condition somehow.
When I type in invalid characters it should go back to beginning and repeat as it's supposed to.
I ran the code step by step on Visual Studio and it shows that code does not even go through while condition. (no matter what the input value is)
Can someone please help me?
Many thanks in advance!

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

namespace a5
{
    class Program
    {
        const string acceptedLetters = "EHLNTXZ";

        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            GetUserString(acceptedLetters);
            ReadKey();
        }

        static string GetUserString(string letters)
        {
            string invalidCharacters;
            do
            {
                invalidCharacters = null;

                Write("Enter : ");

                string inputCharacters = ReadLine();

                foreach(char c in inputCharacters) 
                {
                    if(letters.IndexOf(char.ToUpper(c))==-1)
                    {
                        invalidCharacters = c.ToString();
                    }
                }

                if(invalidCharacters != null)
                {
                    WriteLine("Enter a valid input");
                }
                return inputCharacters;
            } while (invalidCharacters != null);


         } 
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a `return` at the end of the loop, why do you think it will keep going after that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you return the inputed string at the end of the loop no matter the validation done.

You can use a boolean to check this validity.

Also you don't need to parse all the string and you can break the inner loop on the first invalid char.

I renamed the string as `result` to use a standard pattern and to be more clean.

For example:

```
static string GetUserString(string letters)
{
  string result;
  bool isValid;
  do
  {
    Console.Write("Enter : ");
    result = Console.ReadLine();
    isValid = true;
    foreach ( char c in result )
      if ( letters.IndexOf(char.ToUpper(c)) == -1 )
      {
        isValid = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a valid input");
        break;
      }
  }
  while ( !isValid );
  return result;
}
```

Comment: I didn't follow exactly what you wrote but I got the idea of returning after while condition(not returning inside "do") from what you provided.
Thank you Olivier!

Answer (score 0):

The line `return inputCharacters;` makes it leave the loop.

I think you meant:

```
} while (invalidCharacters != null);
return inputCharacters;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

namespace a5
{
    class Program
    {
        const string acceptedLetters = "EHLNTXZ";

        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            GetUserString(acceptedLetters);
            ReadKey();
        }

        static string GetUserString(string letters)
        {
            string invalidCharacters;
            do
            {
                invalidCharacters = null;

                Write("Enter : ");

                string inputCharacters = ReadLine();

                foreach(char c in inputCharacters) 
                {
                    if(letters.IndexOf(char.ToUpper(c))== -1)
                    {
                        invalidCharacters = c.ToString();
                    }
                }

                if(invalidCharacters != null)
                {
                    WriteLine("Enter a valid input");
                }

            } while (invalidCharacters != null);
            return inputCharacters;
         } 
    }
}
```